# Wpf DataGrid is not showing the bound data

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I feel like what I am trying to do is pretty simple and straightforward, but from the research I have done, it looks like I am doing things right. I just made a vanilla WPF project, setup entity framework and now I am trying to bind my employees collection (which has data) to a data grid.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="EmployeesView" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10,10,0,0">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pay Rate" Binding="{Binding PayPerHour}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hire Date" Binding="{Binding HireDate}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Here's my model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public double PayPerHour { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

And here my code behind (not using MVVM)

```
private CompanyContext db = new CompanyContext();
public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

public AddEmployee()
{
    RefreshGrid();
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void RefreshGrid()
{
    Employees = db.Employees.ToObservableCollection();
    EmployeesView = new DataGrid();
    EmployeesView.ItemsSource = Employees;
}
```

`.ToObservableCollection` is an extension method that just casts ienumerable to `ObservableCollection` I have also tried this with `List<>`. For some reason I have to call `EmployeesView = new DataGrid();` other wise `EmployeesView.ItemsSource = Employees;` gives a null ref on `EmployeesView`. That may be where I am going wrong? I'm at a lose here, any ideas?

Comment: *"That may be where I am going wrong?"* - Yes, this is where you are going wrong. I'm assuming this code isn't in your view's code-behind?

Comment: I can confirm that `Employees` has records from the database

Comment: @MikeEason It is, `AddEmployee.xaml` and `AddEmployee.xaml.cs` I have a form on the same page and its bindings are working fine.

Comment: For what I'm looking here you don't have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged on the "item" class, that surely can help with the User Interface to be notified when your data is changed. Another thing I find strange (but maybe it is because the code is not complete) is Why you create a New Datagrid? Assigning the ItemsSource should suffice if the Datagrid is in your Xaml Window or User Control.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs I forgot about INotify, ill be sure to include that. Not sure why I have to create a new datagrid, if I dont I get a null ref when trying to access ItemSource

Comment: RefreshGrid should run after InitializeComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridBInding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataTableItem> _Items;

    public ObservableCollection<DataTableItem> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataTableItem>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    Items.Add(new DataTableItem() { Data = "Data " + i });
            }
        );
        });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

And the item class:

```
public class DataTableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Data;

    public string Data
    {
        get { return _Data; }
        set
        {
            _Data = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

As far as i see you haven't defined your Employees as a public property. Watch my example and do so.

Regarding the Employee, check my DataTableItem and the implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged.

You also have a way of adding items from another thread, just in case you need this scenario when loading your items from the database.

One more thing, do not refresh the grid like that, but try the way i did in my above example :

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<DataTableItem>();
```

or

```
Items.Clear();
```

and then add your items, async or not, this is upon you.

Comment: This did it, the only thing is I could not use the `binding` attribute, had to use `x:Name`, not a huge deal at the moment.